# Angular Material mat-table cdk v9.2.0: Can't bind to 'matHeaderRowDefPosition' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-header-row'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.7
Node: 12.16.2
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.0.7
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core               9.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics         9.0.7
@angular/cdk                       9.2.0
@angular/fire                      6.0.0
@angular/material                  9.2.0
@angular/material-moment-adapter   9.2.0
@ngtools/webpack                   9.0.7
@schematics/angular                9.0.7
@schematics/update                 0.900.7
rxjs                               6.5.5
typescript                         3.7.5
webpack                            4.41.2
```

using directly  selectors.
Tried to enable the sticky header feature of material table (mat-table).

e.g.

```
<div class="scanlist-container">

<mat-table [dataSource]="dataItems">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="techColumn1">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Technical Column</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let dataItem">{{ dataItem.tech }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
</div>
```

console.log error:

> Can't bind to 'matHeaderRowDefPosition' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-header-row'

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, there are two possible solutions:

1. upgrade @angular/cdk from 9.2.0 to 9.2.2
2. replace the angular material selectors with HTML selectors i.e. instead of

> 

```
<mat-table>       --> <table mat-table>
<mat-header-cell> --> <th mat-header-cell> 
<mat-cell>        --> <td mat-cell>
```

the example code from above with changed HTML elements:

```
<div class="scanlist-container">

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataItems">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="techColumn1">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Technical Column</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dataItem">{{ dataItem.tech }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <th mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay; sticky: true"></th>
    <th mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></th>
</table>
</div>
```